# I receive wrong text after uploading SVG file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, svg

In my svg file I have this kind of context:

```
<g transform="matrix(1.00275 0 0 1 373.242 379.375)">
   <text x="960" y="540" id="DIR-A-roadtext" class="fil12 fnt4">S. Osmeña Ave.</text>
</g>
```

and this is my code how I upload the SVG file

```
var reader = new FileReader()
reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]) 
reader.onload = function(f){
   self.output_here = window.atob(f.target.result.slice(26))
   console.log(document.getElementById('DIR-A-roadtext').textContent)
}
```

and this is the result text I get:

**S. OsmeÃ±a Ave.**

Comment: Please update your question with more of a [mcve].

Comment: Could you please try to add encoding attribute in your SVG? `encoding="utf-8"`. For example first line - `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`.